# Convert Async Function that trigger an event to Awaitable Function WP8

Tags: .net-4.5, windows-phone-8

In windows phone 8 to read the contacts from the phone there is only the following code:

```
Dim WithEvents objContacts As New Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts

Private Sub ReadContacts
objContacts.SearchAsync("", Microsoft.Phone.UserData.FilterKind.None, Nothing)
'Result will be read from the event
End Sub

'Event 

Private Sub A_SearchCompleted(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.Phone.UserData.ContactsSearchEventArgs) Handles A.SearchCompleted
Dim B = e.Results.ToList
End Sub
```

My Question is: how can I convert that functionality to Awaitable Function in a Class?

Example:

```
Public Class Contacto

Public Async Function GetContacts() As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of List(Of Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact))

'Do some work: here's my question

End Function

End Class 


'So I can call my function


Dim o as new Contacto

dim Contacts = Await o.GetContacts()
```

Many thanks, I appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call await inside your function , then you will need to add async keyword

```
public async void functionname () //c# syntax
```

Comment: Dear @ap_amp the function SearchAsync is not Awaitable, so can't call it with await: A = Await Awaitable, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question by using the System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource class

```
Public Class CustomContacts
        Dim WithEvents objContacts As New Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts
        Dim tcs As New System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource(Of List(Of Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact))

        Public Async Function GetContacts() As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of List(Of Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact))
            objContacts.SearchAsync("", Microsoft.Phone.UserData.FilterKind.None, Nothing)
            Dim ListContacts = Await tcs.Task

           Return ListContacts
        End Function

        Private Sub objContacts_SearchCompleted(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.Phone.UserData.ContactsSearchEventArgs) Handles objContacts.SearchCompleted
            tcs.SetResult(e.Results.ToList)
        End Sub
    End Class


'So now I can call the function as follow:

dim objContacts as new CustomContacts
Dim myContacts = Await objContacts.GetContacts 'returns List(Of Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact)
```